# If both base and derive class has a same member variable, how compiler resolve which member is to be called?

Tags: c++

```
Look at this example

class base {
public:
    int m1;
    base() {
        m1 = 5;
    }
};

class der:  public base  {
public:
    int m1;
    der() {
        m1 = 6;
    }
};

int main() {
    der d;
    cout << d.m1;   
    return 0;
}
```

Here size of object d is `8 byte`, which is allocated for `2 m1`(one for base class and other for derive class). What is the mechanism to resolve `d.m1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `m1` in `der` hides the name of `base`'s `m1`, so any access to `m1` via a `der` object gets you that instance's `der::m1`. You can access `base::m1` in `der` like this:

```
class der:  public base  {
public:
    int m1;
    der() {
        m1 = 6;
        base::m1=7; // access base object's m1 inside der
    }
};
```

And you can access the base object thus:

```
der d;
d.base; // base object
std::cout << d.base::m1 >> "\n"; // access base object's m1 outside of der (if allowed)
```

Answer (score 5):

The compiler resolves `m1` based on the static type of `d`. This means that you will get different results for

```
der d;
cout << d.m1;
```

and

```
der d;
base &b = d;
cout << b.m1;
```

This is because when resolving `m1` on an expression of type `der`, the member `der::m1` hides `base::m1`.

Comment: And you probably should never do this.